# Uninitialized constant members in classes

Tags: c++

This is probably a ridiculously easy question, but I've been searching around for the answer for a while yet can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to initialize a constant variable constant pointer in a class. Here is the header file:

```
class Scheduler{
  public:
  Scheduler();
  explicit Scheduler( unsigned long * );

  private:
  const unsigned long *const thresh;

};
```

And here is the constructor for the class

```
Scheduler::Scheduler( unsigned long * threshold ):
  thresh(threshold)
{}
```

When I attempt to compile this code I run into this error:

```
scheduler.cpp: In constructor ‘Scheduler::Scheduler()’:
scheduler.cpp:3: error: uninitialized member ‘Scheduler::thresh’ with ‘const’ type ‘const long unsigned int* const’
```

Multiple sources online discussing constant member variables in constructors for member variables point to using initializer lists. I think I'm doing what I'm supposed to, but apparently it's still no good. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the implementation of the default constructor, which is where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must initialize your constant member in the initialization list of ***ALL*** constructors. You are doing it only for the one with an argument. Do it for the default one too, and everything will be fne. In this particular case, either initialize your thresh with 0, or disable the default constructor.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the default constructor, it should be

```
Scheduler::Scheduler() : thresh(0) {}
```

or not be implemented at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (MSVC2010) - as I believe it should. What compiler are you trying this with?
The only complaint a compiler may/should have with the code is a warning that the automatic copy constructor and assignment operator cannot be created because of the const member.

Comment: I think you are referring to "silly-warnings" of VC++. It does not make particularly much sense to warn about these things.

Comment: Your mileage may vary of course ;-) Still, I was missing the default ctor in my answer - the other posters are correct in saying that needs to initialize the const member too.

Comment: So how do I fix the warning? I inherit from `boost::noncopyable` to indicate that the class is not supposed to be copyable/assignable... Two new warnings: now it cannot create implicit copy constructor either! D'oh.