# Constant variable initializing working only with member initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, member-initialization, initialization

Consider the code snippet

```
 class Test{
  const int i;
  public:
 // Test(int x):i(x){} This works
  Test(int x){
      i=x;
  } //this doesn't work
```

Why does the inline member initialization list work while the normal initialization doesn't work?

Comment: What you call "the normal initialization" isn't an initialization. There are plenty of posts hare about initializing data members.

Comment: `i = x;` is not **initialization**. It is **Assignment**. And you can change value of const variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninitialized constant members in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343934/uninitialized-constant-members-in-classes)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `i=x;` is an assignment. If you doesn't initialize it via member intializer list, `i` will be tried to be default-initialized, then assigned in the constructor's body.

But as a const variable, `i` can't be default-initialized (or assigned). So it has to be specified in the [member intializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) for initialization.

> Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.