# Error while trying to use const int std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, constants

Why I'm getting the following error when I try to use an const int std::array?
I had to replace "<" for "<\" in the error message to show it correctly:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<const int, 4> vals;

    return 0;
}
```

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> test.cpp:7:22: error: use of deleted function ‘std::array::array()’
>
> array<\const int, 4> vals;
>                         ^~~~
>
> In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/array:94:12: note: ‘std::array<\const int, 4>::array()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>        struct array
>               ^~~~~
>
> /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/array:94:12: error: uninitialized const member in ‘struct std::array<\const int, 4>’
>
> /usr/include/c++/7.3.0/array:110:56: note: ‘const int std::array<\const int, 4>::_M_elems [4]’ should be initialized
>          typename _AT_Type::_Type                         _M_elems;
>                                                           ^~~~~~~~

Comment: I think it's better to format error messages as code. At least, fixed-width font will make the `^~~~` part align better.

Comment: Then just initialize it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343934/uninitialized-constant-members-in-classes).

Comment: const int make the int unable to change (just at the initialisation). 
Here, you would not be able to change vals after the initialisation, this array is useless. 
Either remove const, or initialize it `array<const int, 4> vals = {1,2,3,4}`

Comment: Both answers below have a typo. [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) is a big problem.

Comment: You want an empty array in read-only memory?

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: @JiveDadson not empty, filled with indeterminate values. Which makes about just as much sense.

Comment: Ah yes, the old "valid but unspecified."

Answer (score 5):

How are you going to assign array values to `const int` elements? You should initialize them during declaration.

```
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<const int, 4> vals{1, 2, 3, 4};

    return 0;
}
```

Without any initialization, your sample is similar to invalid const declaration:

```
const int a;
```

Since `std::array` itself can not be updated, I suppose the below code would be clearer for understanding.

```
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const array<int, 4> vals{1, 2, 3, 4};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the array is in write-only memory.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to the fact that a constant object must be initialized when it is defined. However using this declaration

```
array<const int, 4> vals;
```

you did not provide an initializer.

Consider the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
    int x = 42;
    std::array<const int, 4> vals = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };

    for ( int x : vals ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: What is the purpose of extra braces?

Comment: Why double { { } } to initialize the array?

Comment: @KillzoneKid  Because early some compilers did not allow to initialize an aggregate such a way without extra braces.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Earlier like before C++11? `std::array` exists since C++11 so I think it is safe to assume single braces would work just fine everywhere with this code.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Early means when C++11 was adopted or before its final adoptation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok, thanks for clarifying